# Set a border to UIButton with Star Image

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uibutton, uikit

[image]

I need to set a border to `UIButton` Image. My button images look like this.

I can't use multiple icons for this because the Colors of the image border is server-driven and coming in web service response.

So **I don't want to hardcode 40-50 icons in my codebase. I have only one icon star with a white background.** Please tell me how to achieve this.

**I have tried with `Button.layer.borderWidth` & `Button.layer.borderColor`, but it's giving me a rectangular shape border. I want a star shape border.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to create a system button, and change the tint color of the button based on your requirement
Make sure the star image just consist of the star and rest of the part is transparent.
Then try changing the tintColor of the button

[image]

Here is an image you can use to test.
[image]

Comment: I guess that will work if I want to fill the color in star. I don't want to fill color in star. Only I need is colored border layer on the star.

Comment: That is what my image does as well.. If your star image just has a star with transparent center, changing the tint color would just change the star part. I'll try to create an image for you, so that you could see what I mean..

Comment: Please share the image. I will check & let you know.

Comment: Added an image, since the background is white, it doesn't show up, but here is the URL
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctQjc.png

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Ignore the downvotes as long as the solutions get your work done.

Comment: @Animesh If you wanted to do same by programatically then go with praveen answer (another answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can use "RenderingMode" of UIImage Predefined function, it works for me.

```
  self.imageViewProfile.image = self.imageViewProfile.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
  self.imageViewProfile.tintColor = .white   // This is your border color
```

These 2 lines are for UIImageView, you can use same for your Button. it will surly work

@Updated
For UIButton

```
  let image = UIImage(named: "add")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
  yourButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
  yourButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
```